# Where conditions on top of existing sql - alias columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add dynamic filter conditions to existing sql query, I wrapped the query like:

```
select *
from ( existing sql )
where 1=1 <adding conditions here based on user selection>
```

In the existing sql I have alias columns on which I am not able to do the query's, can anyone let me know how to do it.

Sample eg:

```
select *
from (select firstName as "FN", lastName as "LN", city as "c" 
      from users
     )
WHERE 1 = 1 and FN IN ('John');
```

This is not working, as adding filter on alias column ends in error.

If I dont have alias column in double quotes then its working fine. But I am in need to wrap the existing query and do condition on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an alias for the derived table:

```
select *
from (select firstName as "FN", lastName as "LN", city as "c" 
      from users
     ) x
-------^
WHERE 1 = 1 and FN IN ('John');
```

Note that in MySQL, derived tables are usually materialized.  This can have a big impact on performance, particularly if your query depends on indexes.  This route is a bit dangerous from a performance perspective.

Also, your use of `in` is equivalent to `=`.  The latter is more specific.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the above query is a sample one which I pasted. But In my existing one its a very big query and alias as used in the top select part and now I am not able to wrap it as part select * from () x where 1=1 and "alias column" IN () and do the where conditions, it throws sqlcode=-206, sqlerrmc errors

Comment: If I remove the double quotes in alias name, its working fine and able to do conditions. I am not sure why I am not able to do when alias column as double quotes